# C++ operator overloading - pointer, multiply

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I wonder about the multiply operation(*) is overloading in pointer or vice versa?

Or the operators are individual?

C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works exactly like all of the operator symbols which can define a
unary or a binary operator (`+`, `-` and `&` are the other ones), it
depends on the number of arguments the function will take.  Thus, a
unary `*` should be defined to take a single operator, either as a
non-static class member taking no arguments (other than `this`), or as a
free function taking a single argument.  The binary operator should be
defined to take two arguments, either as a non-static class member
taking one argument (in addition to `this`), or a free function taking
two arguments.

Note that the names of the functions are considered the same, so a
binary version can hide a unary one, or vice versa.

Answer (score 14):

They are separate operators, and which one you overload depends on what parameters you pass to the operator.

```
struct A
{
    //dereference operator
    A /*or whatever*/ operator *() { /*...*/ };
    //multiply operator           
    A operator *(const A&) { /*...*/ };
};

//...
A a;
*a; //calls dereference operator
a * a; //calls multiply operator
```